# refresh cell values before conditional formatting

Tags: excel, refresh, delay, vba

I have a sheet that displays data in shapes to look nice. These shapes simply reference a cell in a data staging sheet. The data in the staging area is using a getpivotdata formula to lookup data.

On my display sheet with the shapes that display values to the user, there is also a combo box that changes the pivot table. When the pivot table is changed it updates the data in the staging area which in turn changes the data in the shapes on the display sheet. I then call a macro that sets the shapes to green if >0 or red if <0.

The problem is that while the pivot data is changing and being recalculated my shapes keep having their colours changed in accordance to the old values as the new fields haven't been calculated yet.

I've tried DoEvents but have little experience as to what it does and had no luck. I don't want to delay by a fixed time because that's just horrible. I've also tried calling StagingSheet.calculate before calling my updateColours macro without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Application.ScreenUpdating = false. E.g.:

```
Sub AllWorkbookPivots()

Dim pt As PivotTable

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables

        pt.RefreshTable

    Next pt
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

That might work.

Answer (score 0):

So to make sure the values are calculated before the colour change is called I used the following macro to make the application wait until the calculations were done.

```
Sub WaitForCalculate()
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub
```

Not very pretty but gets the job done.